# Web Interface: upload/connection timeouts on iOS devices are independent of any actual server timeouts

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, mobile-safari

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- IIS 8+ (several test servers used)
- Web.Config:

  - executionTimeout="3600" (one hour)
  - maxRequestLength="2147483647" (2Gb)
  - maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" (2Gb)

So I am having a very strange issue here. I have built a test site that allows a user to upload an image. This image is then processed by TinyPNG before being dumped directly into the database (a business decision - required by the specifics of the project). On any sort of a full-featured computing platform, such as Windows, MacOS or Linux, I am able to upload an image and proceed completely to the end result which shows me a list of images I uploaded within the “session” of that page (so users can see what they themselves uploaded before navigating away).

On iOS devices, however, this process “times out” in that Safari provides me with a “timed out” response. However, even if I upload 10 images from Safari, all 10 images actually get successfully uploaded. So I know it’s not the server that is timing out -- it’s Safari or something explicitly within iOS.

My research hasn’t really brought anything up. And I have confirmed this issue by physically going to a location with bad cell reception (3G service) and uploading an image that - on LTE - brought me through the full page lifecycle (no timeout). On 3G I still had a successful image upload, but the page once again “timed out”, telling me that this is an iOS issue, and not a transmission or server issue. In fact, my gut reaction is that the “iOS safari timeout” is purely related to time (a 60-second timeout by default, for example) and has nothing to do with actual server timeouts.

I am curious if anyone has run into this issue before, and how you got around this. I am really pulling my hair out here, because I can’t see any way to directly affect how Safari decides to “time out” on its own, and regardless of any actual server timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have answered my own question in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368651/).

What *might* have been happening is that iOS uploads a large image, and then since the large image is passed from the server to TinyPNG, it sits there waiting… and waiting… and waiting for the image to go from the server to TinyPNG and back again. And because it’s a big image, it times out waiting for a response from the server that the entire operation was a success.

By inserting an image resizer between the upload of the image and its initial transmission to TinyPNG, I was able to minimize the data being pushed “over the wire” to TinyPNG and back, and therefore the amount of time the client needed to wait for a response from the server.

I am now able to upload several large images on a very bad connection and not have it time out. Yet. So far. We shall see (with more testing).